# EF.Functions.Like method not working after upgrading to .NET 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I was using **EF.Functions.Like** method for my query on my **ASP.NET Core 3.1 SPI** but as soon as I upgraded it to **.NET 6** along with with all nugets, this particular query started to throw following error

> InvalidOperationException : The Like method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation

I have done some research and I know InMemory databases can cause this issue, but thats not the case I've tried localhosting the API and also published SPI and in both cases the database is always on SQL Server (not local on my machine) so its not an inmemory database, also the fact it worked fine on asp.net core 3.1

**Example query**

[image]

**Query Method**

```
public static async Task<IQueryable<Evidence>> QueryEvidencesAsync(this EvidenceContext Context, EvidenceQuery query)
    {

            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Evidence>();
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.IsActive && x.EvidenceStatus != EvidenceStatus.ReleasedToOwner && x.EvidenceStatus != EvidenceStatus.Transfer);
            if (query.EvidenceStatus is not EvidenceStatus.Disposed)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.IsActive && x.EvidenceStatus != EvidenceStatus.Disposed);
            }
            if (query.EvidenceStatus is not EvidenceStatus.Incoming)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.IsActive && x.EvidenceStatus != EvidenceStatus.Incoming);
            }

            var predicateAndOr = query.IsOr ? PredicateBuilder.False<Evidence>() : PredicateBuilder.True<Evidence>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.CaseNumber))
            {
                predicateAndOr = predicateAndOr.AndOr(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.CaseFileNumber, $"%{query.CaseNumber}%"), query.IsOr);
            }

            predicate = predicate.And(predicateAndOr);
            var predicateCompiled = predicate.Compile();

            return query.IncludeRequests
                ? Context.Evidences.Include(x => x.Requests).AsNoTracking().Where(predicateCompiled).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified)
                : Context.Evidences.Where(predicateCompiled).AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified);
    }
```

**PredicateBuilder**

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>()
    {
        return (T _) => true;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>()
    {
        return (T _) => false;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        InvocationExpression right = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, right), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        InvocationExpression right = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, right), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndOr<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2, bool or = false)
    {
        if (!or)
        {
            return expr1.And(expr2);
        }

        return expr1.Or(expr2);
    }
}
```

in this particular example, **query.IsOr** will always be false so predicate will always build with **And** predicate. Also **query.CaseNumber** will have the string value for **caseNumber**

I have removed many more conditions and if statement all of them just checked for one property and add that check to predicate, but as I said they are not relevant here as in this scenario only the if statements I've shown here are true and hence validated.

Comment: Can you provide any details about the query? It's likely you're doing something that's causing this part of the query to be evaluated as LINQ-to-Objects/Enumerable rather than an Entity Framework query.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Ive updated my question with more details

Comment: Please don't use images for code... formatted text is what we required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building a predicate as an `Expression<Func<Evidence, bool>>`, but then you're `.Compile()`ing it into a `Func<Evidence, bool>`. That means when you call `.Where()` you're no longer calling `Queryable.Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<Evidence, bool>> criteria)`, but rather `Enumerable.Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<Evidence, bool> criteria)`.

The difference there is that the method you're calling will treat the query as an `IEnumerable<T>`, and rather than allowing Entity Framework to issue a query against the database with your criteria as a `WHERE` clause, it will bring *all* of the objects back from the database, and then pass them into the criteria function (which has been compiled into memory) to determine which ones to keep.

In other words, your code in the past was terribly inefficient, and you didn't realize it. `EF.Functions.Like` was never meant to be invoked: it was only supposed to be evaluated as part of a query. Earlier versions of `EF.Functions.Like` did their best to mimic the behavior of SQL's `LIKE` when they were called, whereas newer versions will just throw an exception to warn you that you're doing it wrong.

You need to avoid `.Compile()`, and pass `predicate` directly into your `.Where()` call.

```
            predicate = predicate.And(predicateAndOr);

            return query.IncludeRequests
                ? Context.Evidences.Include(x => x.Requests).AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified)
                : Context.Evidences.Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(x => x.Modified);
```

That may lead to other issues, but it'll get you one step closer to doing it right.

Comment: that worked as u said, however can u explain what other issues this fix might cause?

Comment: I'm considering [Chesterton's fence](https://fs.blog/chestertons-fence/): it's odd that someone went out of their way to add `.Compile()` and `.AsQueryable()` when they don't appear to be necessary. Maybe in the past there was an issue where someone was trying to use logic that couldn't be translated into a SQL query, so they "fixed" it by adding this code without really understanding what was going on. By removing this code, you're undoing their error, but it might help to test all the corner cases, or look back at the git commit where that code was written, to understand what might go wrong.

Comment: In other words, if any of the "many more conditions" you mention does something a little different, like trying to parse a value or something as part of its criterion, enabling that particular condition might cause an exception. Then again, it's possible that nothing in this code required the Compile(), and someone just copied this pattern from another part of code that did. Or it's possible that something else changed since that code was written, making the Compile() no longer necessary.